# How to use template value while calling function?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax, templates

**HTML:**

```
<li data-id="{{Name.first}}" ng-click="getNames('{{Name.first}}')">
```

**Script:**

```
$scope.getNames = function(name) { // I am getting "{{Name.first}}" which I sent. I am not getting the template value
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/some/url",
            params: { value: id },
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.Results = response.data;
        });
    }
```

Please tell me how to use template value while calling the method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass scope variable value without interpolation (`{{}}`) while calling function from `ng-click` directive.

```
<li data-id="{{Name.first}}" ng-click="getNames(Name.first)">
```